# how build and install "mlibc" with and for a gcc cross-compiler?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, libc, meson-build

I wanna create a gcc cross-compiler. I work on a **WSL2 ubuntu 20.04** distrib and the target will be **x86_64-elf** ( for a bare metal project ).

For this learning project, I need to build a C libray with headers and startup files and I don't want use Glibc because, hard to port on a bare metal project. I would like to try the [mlibc](https://github.com/managarm/mlibc) library but I can't find any documentation to achieve my goal.

I was inspired by this [tutorial](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/). How can I from the fourth part of this tutorial + ( Standard C library and standard C++ library ), finish the build of my gcc cross-compiler with mlibc and [meson build system](https://mesonbuild.com/)? ( build system used with mlibc ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use mlibc on bare metal.